# Specifying amount of people to mention from choice

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that selects more than one person in a voice channel and mentions them.

Currently, I have made it so one person is mentioned:

```
@commands.command()
async def hns(self, message):
    await message.channel.send(choice(tuple(member.mention for member in message.author.voice.channel.members if not member.bot)))
    await message.channel.send("You have been chosen to seek.")
```

I have been trying to add an argument in the command such as `arg`, but I am not sure where to go from there.

**Possible solutions:**

I am not used to using the message argument so I'm not sure but maybe using `ctx` instead would allow for more?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument in commands using decorators are always context objects, they're just called `ctx` by convention. This means that your `message` arg is actually the context object.

Another possible solution could be shuffling the list of members and then choosing x number of them, like so:

```py
@commands.command()
async def hns(self, ctx, amount: int):
    members = [m.mention for m in ctx.author.voice.channel.members if not m.bot]
    random.shuffle(members) # shuffles it in place, i.e. doesn't return the list
    selected = members[:amount]
    await ctx.send(f"{', '.join(selected)}, you've been chosen to seek!")
```

The usage of the command would be:
`!hns 3`
Selecting 3 users randomly. This would avoid having to use a hard-coded value, although you can do it that way if you want to.

---

**References:**

- [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)
- [`VoiceChannel.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members)
- [`Member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention)
- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context)

Comment: It works perfectly, but I think that the last line should be a half string? It only works for me like that.

Comment: @ChonkyWonky Oh sorry forgot the `f` before the quotation marks, my bad! Just edited it in. Glad it's working for you though!